# mysql update multiple columns based on most current match in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Running mysql: 5.7.44

I have a table `wInvoices` where I need to update two columns based on the values of the most recent matching record from another table, `wPayments`.  The `wPayments` table holds all CC transactions, success and declined, for each invoice using wInvoices `invID` as the binding/matching column.  Each `invID` could have multiple `wPayments` transactions but I only need to get the most current one; and use the values from that match to populate the `wInvoices` columns.

```
invID,  paidDate,  paidDate, (other columns) = wInvoices
===============================
1001    
1002
1003
1004

pid,  invID,  mDate (other columns)  = wPayments
===================================
2000  1001    2020-07-21 09:31:00 **
2001  1001    2020-07-20 08:20:20
2002  1001    2020-07-20 11:30:30
2003  1002    2020-07-20 09:09:00 **
2004  1003    2020-07-20 11:21:00
2005  1002    2020-07-19 13:30:00 
2006  1003    2020-07-20 13:58:00 **
2007  1004    2020-07-20 09:45:00
2008  1004    2020-07-20 10:00:00 **
```

So that the new values of `wInvoices` is:

```
invID,  paidDate,             paidID, (other columns)
===========================================================
1001    2020-07-21 09:31:00   2000
1002    2020-07-20 09:09:00   2003
1003    2020-07-20 13:58:00   2006
1004    2020-07-20 10:00:00   2008
```

I have read multiple threads on similar types of updates, but have not been able to find anything that matches my exact requirement.  The challenge is accounting for the most recent wPayments record. The closet I can come with is this:

```
UPDATE wInvoices inv SET
  inv.iPaidDate=pay.pDate
  inv.iPaidReceipt=pay.pid
FROM (select pid,pDate from wPayments) pay
 WHERE where inv.invID=pay.invID ;
```

...but this does not account for the most `recent` wPayments record and could end up populating wInvoice columns with data from older records.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 for how to find the most recent row for each invoice. Join with that in your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Can you please run `SELECT VERSION();` and report what it says? The best solution depends on which brand and version of database you are using.

Comment: @BillKarwin  mysql 5.7.44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would write the UPDATE:

```
UPDATE wInvoices inv
INNER JOIN wPayments pay ON inv.invID=pay.invID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wPayments pay2 ON inv.invID=pay2.invID AND pay2.pid > pay.pid
SET
    inv.iPaidDate=pay.pDate
    inv.iPaidReceipt=pay.pid
WHERE pay2.pid IS NULL;
```

The join to `pay2` is an alternative to the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` solution. If we know that `pay` correlates to any row for the given `invID`, we don't want any row `pay2` to exist such that it has the same `invID` and a greater `pid`. We want `pay` to be only the row with the greatest `pid`.

So use an outer join, together with a `WHERE` clause to find only the cases where no row `pay2` is found with a greater `pid`. That means `pay` must be the row with the greatest `pid` of the set of rows matching the respective `invID`.

I'm assuming `pid` is unique.

Comment: It is.  `pid` is unique and no records from that table are ever deleted so there is no chance of a newer record being inserted in place of an older deleted records id

Comment: always better to use a datetime to determine temporal order, not an id (falling back on id to guarantee uniqueness); see my answer

Comment: (I always use left join/where is null myself, but the equivalent where not exists seems to be simpler for some to understand)

Comment: Yes, my solution assumes `pid` is temporally ordered. If that's not reliable, then the date should be used, and the `pid` only as a tiebreaker.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this IMO is:

```
UPDATE wInvoices inv
INNER JOIN wPayments pay ON inv.invID=pay.invID
SET
    inv.iPaidDate=pay.pDate
    inv.iPaidReceipt=pay.pid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM wPayments newer
    WHERE newer.invID=pay.invID AND
        (newer.mDate,newer.pid) > (pay.mDate,pay.pid)
)
```

But I question your database model; why not just select the newest payment information along with the invoice rather than storing it?